# Pytorch: List of layers returns 'optimizer got an empty parameter list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a defined model and defined layer, I add n instances of my defined layer to a list in the init function of my model as follow:

```
    self.layers = []
    for i in range(len(nhid)-1):
        self.layers.append(MyLayer(nhid[i], nhid[i+1]))
```

but when I create optimizer by

```
optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=args.lr, weight_decay=args.weight_decay)
```

it says:

> ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

But when I write it for two layers as follow I got no error:

```
self.layer1 = MyLayer[nhid[0],nhid[1]]
self.layer2 = MyLayer[nhid[1],nhid[2]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `nn.ModuleList()` as follow:

```
temp = []
for i in range(len(nhid)-1):
    temp.append(MyLayer(nhid[i], nhid[i+1]))
self.layers = nn.ModuleList(temp)
```

I also read about `nn.Sequential()`, but I didn't find out how to use it in a correct way.

Answer (score -1):

You have

```
nhid[0], nhid[1], nhid[2]
```

so `len(nhid)` is `3`.

So

```
for i in range(len(nhid)-1):
    self.layers.append(MyLayer(nhid[i], nhid[i+1]))
```

becomes

```
for i in range(2):
    self.layers.append(MyLayer(nhid[i], nhid[i+1]))
```

or

```
self.layers.append(MyLayer(nhid[0], nhid[1]))
self.layers.append(MyLayer(nhid[1], nhid[2]))
```

Compare it with your no-error approach:

```
self.layer1 = MyLayer[nhid[0],nhid[1]]
self.layer2 = MyLayer[nhid[1],nhid[2]]
```

In your first (error) approach you didn't set your object attributes `layer1` and `layer2`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get how I should set object attributes?

Comment: `self.layer1 = ...` `self.layer2 =...`

Comment: my problem is that, which I don't know the number of layers and cannot set the names.